# NextJS - how to dynamically load different apps with dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a multi-lingual application that I use `exportPathMap` but I want to transition to `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. My structure looks like so:

`pages/[language]/[app-slug].js`

However, `[app-slug].js` could be any of 20 different applications with unrelated code...

After reading [caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats) I thought, with pre-defining the `getStaticPaths`, I would be able to do:

```
-[language]
--[app1].js
--[app2].js
...
```

But it throws `You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path ('app1' !== 'app2')`

**Is there any way to dynamically load the react app code based on path, or to have multiple dynamic files in one repo? (all static paths are known)**

[This similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565918/you-cannot-use-different-slug-names-for-the-same-dynamic-path-nextjs) to use query values won't work for my case, SEO and bundle size are top priorities.

Comment: I did find https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9130 which has them saying they don't plan to support this functionality. However, I think there could potentially be a solution with dynamically loading the react code if any one knows of one